# Prove that $\cap_{0<p<\infty}L^p([0,1])\supset L^{\infty}([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Prove that $\cap_{0<p<\infty}L^p([0,1])\supset L^{\infty}([0,1])$.

My work-

let $f \in L^{\infty}([0,1])$. then $\vert f\vert_{\infty}<M\ for some M\ a.e \ on [0,1]$.
we know that $|f|<|f|_{\infty}<M\ a.e$.
then, $|f|^p<M^p\  a.e $
therefore, $\int|f|^p<\int M^p\ which\  is \ finite $.

this implies $f\in \cap_{0<p<\infty}L^p([0,1])$.
hence $\cap_{0<p<\infty}L^p([0,1])\supset L^{\infty}([0,1])$.

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: One small, perhaps nitpicky, issue is that $f \in L^\infty$ implies $\|f\|_{L^\infty} = M < +\infty$ (this is not a pointwise statement). This in turn implies that $|f| < M$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you